# Firebase functions and multipath updates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Been searching a lot on this matter and can't seem to find relevant information. How do you handle multipath updates to the realtime DB, so you don't hit the rateLimitExceeded (number of triggers per 100s on your function's triggers, onWrite, onUpdate, onCreate, onDeleted) ?

Our triggers are set up like this:

```
exports.markersUpdate = functions.database.ref('/v1/markers/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const record = change.after.val();
    const fbKey = context.params.pushId;
    ...
});
```

I thought maybe I could trigger on the parent node like so, but that would return all the collection, not just the updates:

```
exports.markersUpdate = functions.database.ref('/v1/markers').onWrite((change, context) => {
    ...
});
```

This function basically replicates the updates to a datastore for better data analysis. That's been working fine, but our app sometimes need to update a few hundreds records simultaneously, and we get rateLimitExceeded error, even on Blaze plan.

Is there a way to get the list of updated items, so I can process it in the function ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible with Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions handles individual writes as separate function invocations.  There is no batching, and there is no queuing of writes to batch later.

If you want to do a one-time copy of data, you're better off writing a standalone program to query for the data you want to copy, and create your own batch update.

Comment: yeah, I've been going around the problem exactly this way. Had hoped to hear of an new technique to avoid this. Thanks